# Using PIL to create thumbnails results in TextEdit Document extension

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Using PIL, I was able to create a thumbnail of my picture but according to my computer (running `Mac OS X`), my image has an extension of `TextEdit Document` instead of `png` or `jpeg`. I was wondering how can I fix to result in the correct extension.

Here is the code I ran:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> import glob, os
>>> size = 128, 128
>>> pic = glob.glob("cherngloong1.jpg")
>>> im = Image.open(pic[0])
>>> im
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=2048x1365 at 0x100A63BD8>
>>> im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
>>> im.save("cherngloong_thumbnail", "PNG")
>>> im.save("cherngloong_thumbnail1", "JPEG")
```

thumbnail extensions:

[image]

Comment: That looks to be on Mac OS X, right?

Comment: correct sorry I should have mentioned that. updating question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely happening because you aren't saving with a filename extension.

Most modern operating systems use file extensions to determine which program should open a file.

Since you called:

```
>>> im.save("cherngloong_thumbnail", "PNG")
>>> im.save("cherngloong_thumbnail1", "JPEG")
```

the encoding is PNG/JPG, but the extension is not.

Also, for why it is opened by TextEdit, you probably had a readme (or some other text document) that didn't have an extension. When you opened it, you probably did so with TextEdit and so for all files without an extension, OS X opens the files with TextEdit.

To solve your problem save like this:

```
im.save("cherngloong_thumbnail.png", "PNG")
im.save("cherngloong_thumbnail1.jpg", "JPEG")
```

Note that for compatibility, you should save with lowercase letters, as some *nix OSes deal with upper and lower case extensions differently.
And it will be treated like any other image file on your computer.
Read more about file extensions on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension)

Answer (score 2):

I think OSX is just inferring "TextEdit Document" based on the lack of an extension (i.e. `.jpg` or `.png`) in the filename. Try adding one:

```
im.save("cherngloong_thumbnail.png", "PNG")
im.save("cherngloong_thumbnail1.jpg", "JPEG")
```